# How to only show some of the values in an array in an textbox?

Tags: c#

I have come across a problem that i cant salve, What i have is an string array with 60 values in it and they concists of either "vacant" or "reserved". Now what i need to do is to show only those arayy index that are either vacant or reserved and i have no clue on how to go about it. :/ I am stumped to say the least. I know how to get the number of eatch sort in the array so thats no problem.

I just cant figure out how to get those index values into a method that diplays them in my textbox. My thinking is that since i know how many they are i can atleast know the number of iterrations needed to show them all in the textbox.

So please i need some ideas as i am apparently experiencing a major brainfreez :P (both my two grey ones are fighting)

Thanks for any ideas!

//Regards

Comment: Please can you show some code, what have you done so far

Comment: If the string array consists of either "vacant" or "reserved" (no other values) and you say you want to display the array index of *either* vacant or reserved, then its reasonable to say you want to display all indexes.  So the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just traverse the array, building a list of indices that match your condition, e.g.

```
List<int> indices = new List<int>();
for (int i=0; i<myarray.Length; i++)
{
    if (myarray[i] == "reserved") indices.Add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] items= new string[] { "vacant","reserved","reserved","reserved","vacant"};

List<int> vacantIndices=new List<int>();
List<int> reservedIndices=new List<int>();
int indexCounter=0;
foreach (string item in items)
{
    if (item == "vacant")
        vacantIndices.Add(indexCounter);
    else if (item == "reserved")
        reservedIndices.Add(indexCounter);

    indexCounter++;
}

TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", vacantIndices);
TextBox2.Text = String.Join(",", reservedIndices);
```

This will show the Indices of Vacant in `TextBox1` and reservedin `TextBox2` in a comma seperated form (Ex : 1,2,3)